# Why Intel Fortran + Intel MPI report warn(error) when using MPI_Bcast?

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran, intel-mpi

Here is a simple code of fortran with MPI:

```
program mpi_broadcast_example
    use mpi

    implicit none

    integer :: ierr, rank, size, root
    integer :: a

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)

    root = 0

    if (rank == root) then
        ! Initialize the value of variable a on the root process
        a = 42
    endif

    ! Broadcast the value of variable a from the root process to all other processes
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    ! Output the received value of variable a on all processes
    write(*,*) 'Process', rank, ': Received a =', a

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program mpi_broadcast_example
```

It just use MPI_Bcast to pass the `a` to other ranks from rank 0.
When I use Intel Fortran + Intel MPI to compile it, it report a warn：

```
mpiifx test.f90 -o test -warn all
test.f90(21): warning #8889: Explicit interface or EXTERNAL declaration is required.   [MPI_BCAST]
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
---------^
```

I was puzzled by this warning.
I use MPI_Bcast heavily in another project, so there are plenty of warnings, but for other MPI subroutines, there are no warnings at all. Is this a compiler bug? I find it doesn't seem to affect usage, but it does affect mood.
And if I change `implicit none` to `implicit none(type, external)`, an error will be reported directly：

```
mpiifx test.f90 -o test -warn all
test.f90(21): error #8889: Explicit interface or EXTERNAL declaration is required.   [MPI_BCAST]
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
---------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

I wish someone could explain to me what is going on and whether this is a compilation error.

Comment: which versions of Intel compilers and MPI are you using?

Comment: `-warn all` includes `-warn external` and presumably the mpi module doesn't contain an interface for `mpi_bcast`. What happens if you move to the `use mpi_f08` version?

Comment: I confirm the warning with ifort (2021.8.0) rather than ifx. However, it completed the compilation and ran successfully. The warning disappeared with ```use mpi_f08``` (Ian Bush's suggestion).

Comment: The reason the other routines are not complained about is probably because, unlike mpi_bcast, they have no choice arguments with the nett result that they *do* have an interface in the mpi module. I expect mpi_send or mpi_allreduce would also cause a warning, while for example mpi_comm_split won't

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet
Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2021.11 Build 20231005 (id: 74c4a23)
Copyright 2003-2023, Intel Corporation.
ifort (IFORT) 2021.11.1 20231117
Copyright (C) 1985-2023 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Comment: @IanBush Yes, it work. There's no more warn when I move to `use mpi_f08`

Comment: @lastchance Thank you. It does work, `use mpi` is too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, as the warning says, the `mpi` module contains no interface for `mpi_bcast`. The reason no warning is given for the other routines is that the `mpi` module *does* have an interface for these routines.

Why is this? Well you would have to ask the those who implemented the `mpi` module for a definitive answer. But as a step to a guess at an answer let me note `mpi_bcast` has one fundamental difference from the other routines - it has a [choice](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.1/mpi41-report/node37.htm#Node37) argument. In other words the interface for `mpi_bcast` has to deal with lots of different types, kinds and ranks for its first argument, while, for examples and in contrast, `mpi_comm_rank` always takes exactly the same type, kind and rank for all its arguments. Pre Fortran-2003 it was impossible to write an interface for a routine with choice arguments that caught all possible cases. Thus the `mpi` module is *not* required to contain an interface for any routine which has one or more choice arguments. On the other hand the more modern `mpi_f08` module *is* required to contain appropriate interfaces, and changing your code to use this module results in the warning message disappearing:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat bcast_f08.f90
program mpi_broadcast_example
    use mpi_f08

    implicit none

    integer :: ierr, rank, size, root
    integer :: a

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)

    root = 0

    if (rank == root) then
        ! Initialize the value of variable a on the root process
        a = 42
    endif

    ! Broadcast the value of variable a from the root process to all other processes
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    ! Output the received value of variable a on all processes
    write(*,*) 'Process', rank, ': Received a =', a

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program mpi_broadcast_example
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifx -v
ifx version 2023.2.0
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpiifx -warn all bcast_f08.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

On the other hand if we go back to the original program and add another routine with choice arguments it complains about that as well as `mpi_bcast`

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat bcast.f90
program mpi_broadcast_example
    use mpi

    implicit none

    integer :: ierr, rank, size, root
    integer :: a, b

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)

    root = 0

    if (rank == root) then
        ! Initialize the value of variable a on the root process
        a = 42
    endif

    ! Broadcast the value of variable a from the root process to all other processes
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    Call MPI_Allreduce( a, b,  1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )

    ! Output the received value of variable a on all processes
    write(*,*) 'Process', rank, ': Received a =', a

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program mpi_broadcast_example
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpiifx -warn all bcast.f90
bcast.f90(21): warning #8889: Explicit interface or EXTERNAL declaration is required.   [MPI_BCAST]
    call MPI_Bcast(a, 1, MPI_INTEGER, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
---------^
bcast.f90(22): warning #8889: Explicit interface or EXTERNAL declaration is required.   [MPI_ALLREDUCE]
    Call MPI_Allreduce( a, b,  1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )
---------^
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: I should have realized the reason. I actually used to make interface blocks at the call site for the missing ones in my main code, with the actual type used, but then it led to warnings with link time optimizations about non-matching interfaces. Now I just compile my code without `-Wimplicit-interface` when MPI is enabled.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Similarly. In fact almost identically - the last time I tried the mpi_f08 stuff in real anger there were just too many bugs. But this was a while ago, probably in the before times. I should go back and retry.

Comment: I understand why `MPI_Bcast()` might not be in `mpi.mod`, but it does not have to be this way. I just rebuilt the latest MPICH and Open MPI with GNU C/C++ compilers and `ifx 2022.2.1` Fortran compiler and no warning is issued when `mpifort` is invoked with `-warn all`. So this is something I would report to Intel and ask them to fix/enhance their `mpi.mod`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet True nowadays, it is a quality of implementation issue - MPI places no requirement on the implementation of the mpi module (as opposed to the mpi_f08 one) to support such interfaces, but an excellent implementation would do so. But back before F2003 it was not possible to write such interfaces in standard Fortran, hence the lack of requirement. Personally I'd like to see the emphasis of the f_08 stuff and encourage people to use that.